# Sizing Viewboxes in wrapPanel

Tags: wpf, xaml, viewbox, wrappanel

I'm trying to get a wrappanel to display multiple controls that are in a view box to all size automatically so that they will all be displayed as big as they can be without any of them disappearing out of the wrappanel. Here is some simplified code to demonstrate. When the window is resized the buttons will resize but it only makes sure that one full button is visible instead of all of them. Is there a way to make it resize so all of them are visible?

```
<WrapPanel>
    <Viewbox >
        <Button Content="button in viewbox 1" Width="125" Height="50"/>
    </Viewbox>
    <Viewbox >
        <Button Content="button in viewbox 2" Width="125" Height="50"/>
    </Viewbox>
    <Viewbox >
        <Button Content="button in viewbox 3" Width="125" Height="50"/>
    </Viewbox>
</WrapPanel>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRT5i.png)